# Excel Formula Match Case

Tags: excel-formula

**If name in columns A&B appear anywhere in column C&D put MATCH or NO MATCH in Column I

- I tried doing this several ways, `VLOOKUP`... and eventually tried to not include both columns and went with,
  -If cell `E2` appears anywhere in column G, put MATCH in Column I / if no "Match" in column G put “No Match” in column I

Only to get from my formula `#NAME?`, with this idea :-(

`=IF(ISERROR(MATCH(E2,G:G, 0)), "NO Match", INDIRECT(ADDRESS(MATCH(E2,G:G, 0), I)))`

Comment: If you have the name "Alex" in column A, and you have the name "Alexis" in column D, is that considered a match since Alex is contained within Alexis?

Comment: please provide a sample dataset and what the search cells look like

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you are looking for an exact match or if you are also looking for partial match.  IE.  If you have Alex in A and Alexis in C, is that considered a match.

Option 1 - Exact Match

This option means that whatever is in cell A or B has to be excatly in range D or E for a Match to be placed in the corresponding row to value in A or B.

```
=IF(COUNTIF(C:D,$A5)+COUNTIF(C:D,$B5)>0,"MATCH","No Match")
```

Place the above in column I and copy down as needed. C:D may be changed to reflect your range if needed.

[image: POC1]

Option 2 - Partial Match

This is an array formula.  As such limit your C:D range to just the data you are looking at in order to avoid excessive calculations.  to enter an array formula, press <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> instead of just <kbd>Enter</kbd> when completing your formula.  You will know you have done it right when Excel places {} around your formula.  Not these cannot be added manually.

```
=IF(SUM(IFERROR(SEARCH(A14,$C$14:$D$17),0)+IFERROR(SEARCH(B14,$C$14:$D$17),0)),"Match","No Match")
```

Place the above in the appropriate column and copy down as required.  Note the difference when searching for Alex.

[image: POC2]

Answer (score 0):

Assuming a data set like this - where names appear in columns a&b and c&d, and you have a list of names to look for in column f, and the result for each name in column g

```
+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+--+------------+-----------+
| Contact 1 | Contact 2 | Contact 3 | Contact 4 |  | Search for |  Result   |
+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+--+------------+-----------+
| Chris     | Jane      | Tony      | Natasha   |  | Chris      | MATCH     |
| Joe       | Sally     | Steve     | Sam       |  | Steve      | NOT MATCH |
| Robert    | Mary      | Chris     | Jane      |  |            |           |
| Frank     | Kevin     | Joe       | Sally     |  |            |           |
+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+--+------------+-----------+
```

Then the formula used for matching is this:

```
=IF(AND(COUNTIF(A:B,F2)>0, COUNTIF(C:D,F2)>0), "MATCH", "NOT MATCH"
```

(the value in cell F2 is the name being searched for)

Essentially COUNT the number of times the name appears in cols A&B, COUNT the number of times name appears in columns C&D. If both are >0 then there is a match

Comment: Not exactly, Column E, ID_FAMILY_NAME and column F, ID_GIVEN_NAME may / or may not be in column G, ID_FAMILY_NAME and H, ID_GIVEN_NAME... they are first and last names. I just need to put "done" in column "I" if there is a match if this makes sense..